# avoid SwiftSupport folder in .ipa

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift

In latest Xcode 7.1.1, ipa created has SwiftSupport folder. It increased ipa size around 20MB.

Old Xcode not added SwiftSupport folder inside ipa

How to avoid SwiftSupport folder in ipa ?

Comment: Guru did you solve this issue? Please le me know if you have resolved it. In Xcode 10.1 and above iPA size increasing by 100MB because of these files

Comment: @SanthoshShettigar Please read below answer from Christin: HOWEVER, it does not matter how big your IPA file is (if that's your concern) because Apple removes the folders on processing via iTunes connect. So I just ignored build size.

Answer (score 11):

**Disable "Embedded Content Contains Swift Code" in your application build settings.**

As @Rob Napier mentioned, but you can also set this flag to **NO** if you have a swift code project. The flag only means if you have an ObjC project which includes Swift code via a framework to indicate that you need swift support.

**HOWEVER, it does not matter how big your IPA file is (if that's your concern) because Apple removes the folders on processing via iTunes connect** As stated by an Apple Developer in the forums: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16339

Comment: quote: "The size of libswiftCore.dylib in your IPA, and the size of your IPA in general, is somewhat meaningless these days."

Comment: I tried setting it NO and YES, in both ways it adds SwiftSupport folder. Still App Size is more.

Comment: Yes, but as I said and the apple dev stated: It does not matter if it's included in the ipa file because the app store will process it out.

Comment: Is there any way to remove it out from ipa? No way ?

Comment: @NatureFriend I don't think so. As Swift is evolving they want to support also older versions of Swift. As soon as Swift is "stable" they will remove this behaviour I guess. (like for objc) But that's only my personal opinion.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other explanations I would also recommend to upgrade to Xcode 7.2. According to my research, there is no "SwiftSupport" folder included when building the ipa file when using Xcode 7.2. (As indicated by other answers, it is assumed you are not using Swift in the project.)

Comment: its a swift project, but I tried Xcode 7.1.1, will try Xcode 7.2 as soon as possible.

Comment: it's about including swift code from elsewhere not the project itself - please post the outcome @NatureFriend , would be very interesting if they removed the behaviour in 7.2

Answer (score 0):

Disable "Embedded Content Contains Swift Code" in your application build settings.

[image]

This of course assumes that you don't have any Swift code in your project. If you do, then you need to include the Swift standard libraries, which are contained in that folder.

The default for this setting is "No" so it's likely that something you're importing (CocoaPods?) is setting it. Or that something you're importing actually has Swift code in it....

Comment: I tried setting it NO and YES, in both ways it adds SwiftSupport folder. Still App Size is more.